# Is asking duplicate questions to improve searchability okay?

Tags: support, search, duplicate-questions

There's a certain answer which contains something very useful to me which I fairly regularly go back and reference, however I often have difficulty finding the Q&A again because the question is different to what I want from the answer. I've since just saved a copy of the answer on my phone since it was difficult to search from Google or the site's search.

Would it be okay to ask a better phrased question and then have it marked as a duplicate of the other question since while the questions are different the answer of the other one will provide an answer to the new question while also providing a simpler and more efficient way to search for the Q/A.

Is it okay to ask duplicate questions for this purpose?

Comment: Can't you just mark the question as a favourite? Alternatively, can you in good conscience improve the title/phrasing of the existing question without changing its meaning?

Comment: I've corrected my typo, I meant mark the question as a favourite so you can find it more easily.

Comment: @RobertLongson ah yes I probably could, that sounds like what i'm after. This question is still valid though as it would help other people with the same question.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that your statement of the problem is common enough for people to use it in preference to the existing question then yes asking the new question is acceptable, but only if the original question can't be edited so that it **does** turn up in said search. Stack Exchange works best when the question(s) contain the common search terms.

I wouldn't reference the original question in the text of your's though. People might not understand what you're trying to do and could start down-voting.

If you have enough reputation then vote to close yourself, or alternatively link to the original question in a comment.

**However**, if you're doing this just so you can find the question again it would be far simpler to mark it as a "favorite" by clicking the star just below the voting arrows. This will save a link in your profile. All you have to do then is remember which one of your favourite questions it is :)

Comment: Signposts can help others, but creating them intentionally requires a lot of consideration of various aspects - what makes a signpost useful, or even if it's necessary in the first place, how effective searches currently are to the duped question, keywords, how popular the duped question is, etc etc. Not sure we should be suggesting this is "ok" to do given the potential for abuse, and even just poor signpost creation unintentionally. Doesn't ring true to me: "It's ok to knowingly create a duplicate"

Comment: @James - Normally I'd agree with you. However, if the original doesn't turn up for what should be a common search term then it is something that should be considered.

Comment: @ChrisF I agree. That kills a lot of people. People try searching something, and find nothing. They ask, they get down voted into oblivion, they leave. *Even when they did search*. If you don't know what a wildcard import is, and you search [python import *](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+import+*) There's nothing that resembles that search, and you instead get posts about yielding and decorating. This happened to me when I started programming. I thought that there was an auto-function called * and couldn't find anything in the docs, and nothing here. So I asked. And I nearly left.

Comment: @Zizouz212 and ChrisF I understand the potential usefulness of signposts, I just don't think users should be attempting to create them manually. Fine if they inadvertently create a question which is dupe, we have a new signpost with more searchable keywords, but there's too much to consider for users to be able to make them manually and be quality and worthwhile (and I include myself in "users" inability too) (Also, I didn't dvote, just wanted you to know FWIW)

Comment: Manually generated signposts are likely to also have keywords irrelevant to the duped questions, which over time would make it harder for people to find relevant things because the site ends up with too many searchable keywords. Dupes are not good if the original question is easy to find, and many users won't accurately deduce if it was their poor search ability or if a question is hard to find for others too, plus other complex requirements. Manual signposts would mostly be based on their own experience, which doesn't necessarily suit everyone else. Just IMO, we could debate this for ever :)

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be okay to ask a better phrased question

If you feel you can ask a better phrased question, why not instead utilise the text and wording you would have used in a new question and improve the current one?

**I'm not** suggesting you edit to make it more pleasing or searchable for your needs, but part of the Stack Exchange culture is to edit and *improve* the content.

---

> Is it okay to ask duplicate questions for this purpose?

You want to make a new question on the site, which you know is a duplicate, utilise site resources such as database storage, and network, and waste other users time from their reading it, all to essentially use it as a "*personal bookmark*"?

No, obviously :)

Use "bookmarks" or "favourites" or find specific keywords in the question you want to refer back to frequently so you can successfully locate if from a search.